# Nativescrip multiple screen resolutions

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

How to support multiple screen resolutions with Vue? I couldn't find anything about multiple resolutions supporting on nativescript-vue.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default measurement is DIP (Density Independent Pixels) that makes your app mostly look good on different resolution.

But if you still prefer to write CSS specific to a platform / device / screen resolution / orientation, try [nativescript-platform-css](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css).

If you want to completely change the layout of your page then you might have to write  different components and load them based on your [screen resolution](https://docs.nativescript.org/ns-framework-modules/platform).